# Boost.Asio async_write/async_read - programs do not communicate properly

Tags: boost, asynchronous, boost-asio, message

Good day.

I'm trying to implement a question - answer logic using boost::asio.

On the Client I have:

```
void Send_Message()
{
 ....
 boost::asio::async_write(server_socket, boost::asio::buffer(&Message, sizeof(Message)), boost::bind(&Client::Handle_Write_Message, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
 ....
}


void Handle_Write_Message(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
 ....
 std::cout << "Message was sent.\n";
 ....
 boost::asio::async_read(server_socket_,boost::asio::buffer(&Message, sizeof(Message)), boost::bind(&Client::Handle_Read_Message, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
 ....
}

void Handle_Read_Message(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
 ....
 std::cout << "I have a new message.\n";
 ....
}
```

And on the Server i have the "same - logic" code:

```
void Read_Message()
{
 ....
 boost::asio::async_read(client_socket, boost::asio::buffer(&Message, sizeof(Message)), boost::bind(&Server::Handle_Read_Message, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
 ....
}


void Handle_Read_Message(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
 ....
 std::cout << "I have a new message.\n";
 ....
 boost::asio::async_write(client_socket_,boost::asio::buffer(&Message, sizeof(Message)), boost::bind(&Server::Handle_Write_Message, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
 ....
}


void Handle_Write_Message(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
 ....
 std::cout << "Message was sent back.\n";
 ....
}
```

Message it's just a structure.

And the output on the Client is: `Message was sent.`
Output on the Server is: `I have a new message.`

And that's all. After this both programs are still working but nothing happens. 
I tried to implement code like:

```
if (!error)
{
 ....
}
else
{
 // close sockets and etc.
}
```

But there are no errors in reading or writing. Both programs are just running normally, but doesn't interact with each other.
This code is quite obvious but i can't understand why it's not working.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Is the underlying socket a unix or inet socket?

You might want to try a tool like tcpdump or wireshark to watch the exchange between the client and server.

Answer (score 0):

I always forget to call run() or poll() on my boost::asio::io_service. Are you calling that? Because boost requires that called periodically in order to send/receive.

Comment: The io_service is running as in the example of boost::asio: boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));